# Что выбрать: Canvas или SVG?

Tags: html5, canvas, svg

Цель: разработать простенькое игровое поле для игры (шахматы) с возможностью анимации перемещения фигур, в результате будет он-лайн игра в реальном времени.

SVG больше нравится тем, что графика векторная и более "красивая", и даже с помощью того самого Adobe Illustrator можно нарисовать поле, все фигуры и т.д.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта имеют свои плюсы и минусы.
SVG хорош тем, что он векторный. Однако рендерится гораздо дольше чем canvas. Много svg элементов на странице будут ощутимо тормозить.
Canvas рендерится быстро, т.к. это растровая графика. Но отображения под ретину например придется немного пошаманить.
В принципе для обоих решений есть библиотеки - реализовать анимацию не проблема в обоих случаях.
Так как активных элементов немного - имеет смысл использовать SVG